# Are gargoyles a magic species, jinxed stone or something else in Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter

> The two stone gargoyles that usually guarded the entrance to the staffroom had been smashed apart by a jinx that had sailed through another broken window. Their remains stirred feebly on the floor, and as Harry leapt over one of their disembodied heads, it moaned faintly. “Oh, don’t mind me… I’ll just be here and crumble…”

What is the gargoyles in the Harry Potter? Are they a magic species, jinxed stone or something else?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Gargoyles are not in *Fantastic Beast And Where To Find Them* which would mean they are not a magical species. So working from this i think we can safely assume that they, like many other feature of the castle are enchanted. Examples of this are the enchanted suits of armor, and enchanted portraits. We also have examples of teachers themselves enchanting objects to essentially bring them to life, like Professor Mcgonagall's chess set, as well as in the final book, the teachers brought to life most of the statues, to use in defense of the castle.

In short, Statues, with some form of enchantment.

Comment: IOW, they are basically just statues

Comment: Anyone with their Fantastic beasts books at hand confirm this for me, and ill edit and remove the AFAIK.

Comment: Confirmed - the search of the e-book for "garg" finds nothing.

Comment: @DVK Since you have an ebook, does *Fantastic Beasts* only list creatures designated "Beasts", or does it include "Beings" as well? It's not impossible (although it is unlikely) that gargoyles could be considered a Being

Comment: @JasonBaker - what do you mean by "being"?

Comment: @DVK [With apologies for referencing the alleged Wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Being). Goblins, vampires, hags, giants, house-elves, veela, and werewolves all seem to be considered "Beings". I think they talk more about this in one of the prefaces to *Fantastic Beasts*

Comment: @JasonBaker - ah. Gotcha. NONE of those "creatures" on the list above appears in the book as a separate listing, aside from prefaces, if that's what you're asking. And gargoyles aren't mentioned in the prefaces either.

Comment: According to Fantastic Beasts (EU Portuguese), translated to english, my annotations under double brackets (( this)) :

A being ((= not a monster)) is any creature intelligent enough to understand the laws of the magical community and to take part in the responsibility of creating them. ((The exception to this is Centaurs as they requested to be considered monsters - also in Fantastic Beasts))

Comment: There are also no references to Gargoyles nor any other beasts that turn into stone, wood or any other type of material